# DVCS with "named commits"

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I'm looking for a DVCS which would allow me to use something like a "named commit" -- similar to what patch queues achieve, but not quite... (I'll compare only to `mq` and `stg`, since I don't know of any other similar ones)

Patch queues are close, but I'd like those features:

- Creating new branch in the repository, branches also the patch series. (m`q` uses global patch queues, `git` loses the `stg` information while branching and branches with patches currently applied)
- Ability to list the "named commits", pop and push them just like patches. (both do that)
- Tying the "named commit" changes to normal commits - so that when I create a patch at rev 1, I change the patch at rev 3, I can still checkout rev 1 and see the old version. (`mq` is global again, `stg` fails with "not on any branch" when I come back to older revision)
- Same as above really - ability to tag a revision in a way that if I check it out, I get the "named commits" I had then.

Is there anything similar out there? Any extensions to some DVCS? Or maybe there's a way to make `mq` or `stg` behave the way I want? Any suggestions?

It seems like `mq` which keeps its information is in the same repo as other files, would be close to what I need, but is that even possible?

---

Just to explain the purpose quickly: I want to keep the patches applied all the time, but they're not "part of development". I just want several specific features kept separately in my own fork of the main repo.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tag

Comment: I could use tags, but I'd have to name them in some specific way. If create 2 "special tags" then branch and remove the first (and only that) tagged commit in that branch - how can I easily tell which patches are applied right now and which aren't? Although, I'll check if I can somehow script it in mercurial... if it was done seamlessly, it would be a really sweet solution! Thanks for this idea.

Comment: I've started recently to use named branches in mercurial for each feature I develop and merge it when it's finished. Only typos and hotfixes are done directly in the default branch. Alternatively you can also use tags, if you are looking for a more lightweight solution.

Comment: Just as there are good reasons to put repository control information under VCS (e.g. hg add .hgignore), it may either be a great or horrible idea to VCS `my_tag_info_metadata.{csv,json}`; I haven't determined yet.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you want to keep your personal fork in patch queue format.  what's wrong with just creating an extra branch or two, and rebasing ontop of master as needed?

Comment: @Zed - Some local patches might be applied to many branches and then might be accepted upstream, but after a slight rewrite. Keeping them explicit and named would enable easier merging - I know which patch to remove (by issue name for example) when the time comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Mercurial by using `mq` inside of its own repo. Most commands have a `--mq` flag that will operate on the patch queue. To get started use `hg init --mq` (`hg qinit` also works, but that pattern is more limited, especially since `qpush` would be overloaded). This creates a repo inside of `.hg/patches`, which is independent from the main repo. Then, use `mq` as usual. When you want to commit your patch queue, use `hg commit --mq`.

You can also tag and branch with the `--mq` flag, to keep track of different heads. Unfortunately, it looks like the Bookmarks extension does not yet support mq, which would be nice since you probably want lightweight labels. If you wanted, though, you could set up an alias for `qbookmark` which just adds the `-R .hg/patches` so it operates on the patch queue repo.

I haven't used this extensively myself, but it looks like enough of the native Mercurial commands support `--mq` as to make it a possible solution for you.